# Change order of polygons within a feature layer? (arcgis js 4.xx)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I have tried using the below in my initial query, and query right before drawing my polygons with class breaks.

```
    query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
```

However this did not seem to do anything. I have also tried using **grid_value** field as well.

Here is my relevant code in which I am querying and then doing the drawing... main problem is occasionally large polygons block out smaller ones.. I can mostly see them, but visibility is not the issue.. I need to be able to click them as well.. if the smaller polygons would draw on top most layer, or even higher grid values on top should solve it. I found **orderByFields** in the docs but doesn't seem to do anything at all...

```
query.outFields = ["*"];
  //query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
  query.returnDistinctValues = false;
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  QT.execute(query).then(function (evt) {
    evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
      var att = feature.attributes
      var test = geometryEngine.convexHull(feature.geometry)
      var genpoly = null
      if (att.grid_value <= 4.0) {
        var rad = att.Shape__Length / 75
        genpoly = new Circle({
          center: test.centroid,
          radius: rad,
          radiusUnit: "meters"
        })
      } else {
        genpoly = test
      }
      var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: genpoly,
        attributes: att,
        type: "polygon"
      });
      gras.push(polygonGraphic);
    });
    var renderer = {
      type: "class-breaks",
      field: "grid_value",
      classificationMethod: "esriClassifyManual",
      classBreakInfos: [{
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 1.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "I (Not Felt)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 2.0,
          maxValue: 3.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [191, 204, 255, .3],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "II (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 3.1,
          maxValue: 3.9,
          symbol: {
            color: [153, 153, 255, .4],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "III (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.0,
          maxValue: 4.5,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 255, 255, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IV (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.5,
          maxValue: 4.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [125, 248, 148, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "V (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 6.0,
          maxValue: 6.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 255, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VI (Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 7.0,
          maxValue: 7.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 221, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VII (Very Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 8.0,
          maxValue: 8.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 145, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VIII (Severe) "
        },
        {
          minValue: 9.0,
          maxValue: 9.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IX (Violent)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 10.0,
          maxValue: 10.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [221, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "X"
        },
        {
          minValue: 11.0,
          maxValue: 11.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XI"
        },
        {
          minValue: 12.0,
          maxValue: 12.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [68, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XII"
        }
      ]
    }
         var popupTrails = {
             outFields: ["*"],
             "title": "Shake ID: {id}",
            "content": function (feature){
              let name_plc;
              let dlv = document.createElement("div");
              dlv.className = "popd";
              dlv.innerHTML = `<b><span class='name_plc'></span></b><br>ID: <span class="ida">${feature.graphic.attributes.id}</span><br> URL: <a href="${feature.graphic.attributes.url}" target="_blank">View</a> <br> Updated: ${feature.graphic.attributes.updated} <br>Grid_value: ${feature.graphic.attributes.grid_value}<br> Event Time: ${feature.graphic.attributes.eventTime} <style>.esri-popup__navigation { display: none;}</style>`;
              
              getName();
              
              function getName() {
               let cId = $('span.ida').text();
               if (cId) { 
                  //console.log(cId);
                  let q3 = new Query();
                  q3.where = "id = '"+ cId +"'";
                  q3.outFields = ["*"];
                   QTt.execute(q3).then(function (results) {
                      results.features.map(function (feat) {
                        let pID = feat.attributes["id"];
                        if (cId === pID) {
                           name_plc = feat.attributes["place"];
                             console.log(name_plc);
                             let tx = $('.name_plc').text();
                             if (tx == 0){
                               $(".name_plc").append(name_plc);
                             }
                        }
                      });
                  });
              } else {
                setTimeout(getName, 230);
              }
             }
              return dlv; 
      },
    };
    fl = new FeatureLayer({
      source: gras,
      objectIdField: "ObjectID",
      geometryType: "polygon",
      fields: [{
        name: "ObjectID",
        alias: "ObjectID",
        type: "oid"
      }, {
        name: "id",
        alias: "id",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "updated",
        alias: "Last Update",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "eventTime",
        alias: "eventTime",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "url",
        alias: "url",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "grid_value",
        alias: "grid_value",
        type: "double"
      }],
      renderer: renderer,
      popupEnabled: true,
      //outFields: ['*'],
      popupTemplate: popupTrails,
      visibleElements: [{
          featureNavigation: false, 
      }],
    });
    map.add(fl);
```

Here is my full [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camerondevcam/pen/pogPZvX?editors=1100) as well.. Any way to do this client side javascript? simply change index to smallest polygons on top?! 1/3 times some of my polygons render in the correct order.. but I need to ensure they all always do, so they are visible and I can click them.

---

**Update:**

Here is a better screenshot: For instance, I try to click the green shape in the middle, the largest blue circle highlights and the popup only displays the meta for that one. Cannot click the smaller inner ones.

i.e. before click.

[image]

i.e. after trying to click the green inner small polygon -- only outer is accessible.

[image]

perhaps the issue is my *order by clause* needs to be handled within my filter?

```
 eqLayerView.filter = {
          outFields: "*",
          orderByFields: "Shape__Area DESC",
          where: "id IN (" + sqlExp + ")"
        };
```

Comment: I actually check it and `query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];` is working fine, every feature is in descendant order by that field. When is not working?

Comment: The polygons are still being overlapped by the larger ones... like in the screenshot

Comment: also would it be DESC or ASC? on geonet forms they are saying it should be ASC, the goal is for the smallest polygons to always be on top of the larger polygons so all polygons are accessible to click or view. i.e. https://community.esri.com/message/940208-re-reorder-order-smallest-on-top-polygons-in-feature-layer?commentID=940208&et=watches.email.thread#comment-940208

Comment: Render is in order, so it is you did right, `Shape__Area DESC` should render polygons with largest area first. I don't really understand the image, I actually try to see it and for me renders OK, what is the feature of the example?

Comment: The visibility is Okay, not great, but doable.. the problem is due to overlapping occasionally you cannot 'click' the small polygons, because the larger ones are in front of it. I think you are not understanding my issue. You may see them because I changed the opacity of the larger ones, so you can see them through it - but you cannot always click them - they seem to render sometimes properly, and sometimes with the largest ones blocking the smaller ones from being clicked. I am trying solve, where they smallest ones are always clickable

Comment: I do understand the problem, but if I try your code with query order by area I have the correct result, that means I am seeing different that your picture. If I click on the "middle" it shows me 15 features, and all ordered visually from larger to smaller. I thing the layer is not helping, many of the features are not showing, and overlap is not the reason, to check this use a style with just borders, no fill.

Comment: It seems to come back arbitrarily, sometimes it renders in proper order, sometimes it does not, I am experiencing it again with or without the query

Comment: I do not care about the checkbox order, its the order of the polygons... click an earthquake in Mexico for instance (check turns it on), this quake makes up of several polygons, sometimes the smaller ones render behind the larger ones and I cannot click.. query order by clause does not seem to be working in my testing, consistently atleast.

Comment: If this involves SQL, please provide the generated SQL statement(s).  And the table schema.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example, is base on your code, I just remove lot of things and keep the important ones to see that sort by area works. Like I told you, the layer plus the renderer did not help you to realize this. Just click and you will see each feature been selected.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>OrderByFields - Render order</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
      "esri/geometry/Circle",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
      "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
      "esri/tasks/support/Query"
    ], function (
      Map,
      MapView,
      FeatureLayer,
      geometryEngine,
      Circle,
      Graphic,
      SimpleFillSymbol,
      QueryTask,
      Query) {

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "gray"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-122, 37],
        zoom: 2
      });

      let fl;
      let gras = [];
      let dVals = [];

      const QT = new QueryTask({
        url: "https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1"
      });

      const query = new Query();
      query.where = "eventTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND updated >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND grid_value > 2 AND id = 'us6000ah9t'";
      query.outFields = ["*"];
      query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
      query.returnDistinctValues = false;
      query.returnGeometry = true;
      QT.execute(query).then(function (evt) {
        evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
          const att = feature.attributes
          console.log(att.Shape__Area);
          const test = geometryEngine.convexHull(feature.geometry)
          let genpoly = null
          if (att.grid_value <= 4.0) {
            const rad = att.Shape__Length / 75
            genpoly = new Circle({
              center: test.centroid,
              radius: rad,
              radiusUnit: "meters"
            })
          } else {
            genpoly = test
          }
          att.newArea = geometryEngine.geodesicArea(genpoly);
          const polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: genpoly,
            attributes: att,
            type: "polygon"
          });
          gras.push(polygonGraphic);
        });

        fl = new FeatureLayer({
          source: gras.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.attributes.newArea < b.attributes.newArea) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.attributes.newArea > b.attributes.newArea) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          }),
          objectIdField: "ObjectID",
          geometryType: "polygon",
          fields: [
            {
              name: "ObjectID",
              alias: "ObjectID",
              type: "oid"
            }, {
              name: "id",
              alias: "id",
              type: "string"
            }, {
              name: "grid_value",
              alias: "grid_value",
              type: "double"
            }, {
              name: "Shape__Area",
              alias: "Original Area",
              type: "double"
            }, {
              name: "newArea",
              alias: "Process Area",
              type: "double"
            }
          ],
          popupTemplate: {
            title: "{id}",
            content: [
              {
                type: "fields",
                fieldInfos: [
                  {
                    fieldName: "grid_value",
                    label: "Grid Value"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "Shape__Area",
                    label: "Old Area"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "newArea",
                    label: "Process Area"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          renderer: {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
              type: "simple-fill",
              color: [255, 0, 0, 1],
              outline: {
                width: 1,
                color: "black"
              }
            }
          }
        });
        map.add(fl);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

After reviewing your update, I think I understand better the issue and I notice something that I miss before, `featureNavigation: false`. I am pretty sure that on click all features are selected, the problem is that the one you want is not the fist one to appear. In other words, you have a problem with the order in witch popup is showing clicked features.

So, I will propose you a simple solution, manually open the popup with the desire feature (in you case the one with less area). For this, you need to:

1. disable popup auto open
2. handle view click event
3. use view hittest method to get features
4. open popup with the desire feature

Take a look at this example I made for you, I add an extra condition to retrieve some features to make it faster

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>esriFieldTimeDate</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
      "esri/geometry/Circle",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
      "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
      "esri/tasks/support/Query"
    ], function (
      Map,
      MapView,
      FeatureLayer,
      geometryEngine,
      Circle,
      Graphic,
      SimpleFillSymbol,
      QueryTask,
      Query) {

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "gray"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-122, 37],
        zoom: 2
      });

      let fl;
      let gras = [];

      const QT = new QueryTask({
        url: "https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1"
      });

      function newAreaCompareFunction(a, b) {
        if (a.attributes.newArea < b.attributes.newArea) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.attributes.newArea > b.attributes.newArea) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }

      const simpleRenderer = {
        type: "simple",
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-fill",
          color: [255, 0, 0, 1],
          outline: {
            width: 1,
            color: "black"
          }
        }
      };
      const docRenderer = {
        type: "class-breaks",
        field: "grid_value",
        classificationMethod: "esriClassifyManual",
        classBreakInfos: [{
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 1.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "I (Not Felt)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 2.0,
          maxValue: 3.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [191, 204, 255, .3],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "II (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 3.1,
          maxValue: 3.9,
          symbol: {
            color: [153, 153, 255, .4],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "III (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.0,
          maxValue: 4.5,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 255, 255, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IV (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.5,
          maxValue: 4.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [125, 248, 148, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "V (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 6.0,
          maxValue: 6.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 255, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VI (Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 7.0,
          maxValue: 7.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 221, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VII (Very Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 8.0,
          maxValue: 8.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 145, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VIII (Severe) "
        },
        {
          minValue: 9.0,
          maxValue: 9.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IX (Violent)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 10.0,
          maxValue: 10.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [221, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "X"
        },
        {
          minValue: 11.0,
          maxValue: 11.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XI"
        },
        {
          minValue: 12.0,
          maxValue: 12.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [68, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XII"
        }
        ]
      };

      const query = new Query();
      query.where = "eventTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND updated >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND grid_value > 2 AND id = 'us6000ah9t'";
      query.outFields = ["*"];
      query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
      query.returnDistinctValues = false;
      query.returnGeometry = true;
      QT.execute(query).then(function (evt) {
        evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
          const att = feature.attributes
          console.log(att.Shape__Area);
          const test = geometryEngine.convexHull(feature.geometry)
          let genpoly = null
          if (att.grid_value <= 4.0) {
            const rad = att.Shape__Length / 75
            genpoly = new Circle({
              center: test.centroid,
              radius: rad,
              radiusUnit: "meters"
            })
          } else {
            genpoly = test
          }
          att.newArea = geometryEngine.geodesicArea(genpoly);
          const polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
            geometry: genpoly,
            attributes: att,
            type: "polygon"
          });
          gras.push(polygonGraphic);
        });

        fl = new FeatureLayer({
          source: gras.sort(newAreaCompareFunction),
          objectIdField: "ObjectID",
          geometryType: "polygon",
          fields: [
            {
              name: "ObjectID",
              alias: "ObjectID",
              type: "oid"
            }, {
              name: "id",
              alias: "id",
              type: "string"
            }, {
              name: "grid_value",
              alias: "grid_value",
              type: "double"
            }, {
              name: "Shape__Area",
              alias: "Original Area",
              type: "double"
            }, {
              name: "newArea",
              alias: "Process Area",
              type: "double"
            }
          ],
          popupTemplate: {
            title: "{id}",
            content: [
              {
                type: "fields",
                fieldInfos: [
                  {
                    fieldName: "ObjectID",
                    label: "Object ID"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "grid_value",
                    label: "Grid Value"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "Shape__Area",
                    label: "Old Area"
                  },
                  {
                    fieldName: "newArea",
                    label: "Process Area"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          renderer: docRenderer
        });
        map.add(fl);

        view.goTo(
          gras
            .map(f => f.geometry.extent)
            .reduce(
              (p, c) => p ? p.union(c) : c
            )
        );

        view.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false; // <- disable view popup auto open
        view.on("click", function (event) { // <- listen to view click event
          view.hitTest(event, { include: fl }) // <- retrieve features
            .then(function (response) {
              if (response.results.length) {
                var feature = response.results // <- get desire feature 
                  .map(result => result.graphic)
                  .reduce(
                    (p, c) => 
                    p ? (c.attributes.newArea < p.attributes.newArea ? c : p) : c
                  )
                  ;
                view.popup.open({ // <- open popup
                  location: event.mapPoint, // <- use map point of the click event
                  features: [feature] // <- add the desire feature
                });
              }
            });
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again for looking - but I need to keep that for my custom polygons.. I do not want to sacrifice functionality to achieve lol

Comment: I just update the snippet to add a second order, because I realize that you could actually be changing areas, not sure but just in case. Plus I added a simple renderer opaque just o show you that the shapes are rendered in the desire order. BTW, the things I remove were just to make code small, doesn't change your custom polygons. I just want you to see that ordering features by area works.

Comment: @docholiday .. maybe I am not following you, sorry for that

Comment: But you had removed the colors/styles per polygon?

Comment: But I thought the problem was that some polygons stay behind bigger polygons, and that complicate the interaction with them .. If that is the problem then style is not the issue, I mean it helps, but the small polygons with the problem will keep the problem .. If not, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that is the problem, but i need to keep the colors as well, per requirement, will try to integrate your code.